# updating the URDF after changing the physical device on the robot

Tags: ros, urdf, moveit, ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello !

I'm working on my robot arm for grasping task using a RGBD camera to detect an object and feedback the position of an object to grasp.

Recently, I changed the camera on the robot, so I have to also update the URDF for the MoveIt, but I'm not sure that updating only the URDF is the right answer.

So my question is I would like to know the process of updating, after I changed the physical device on the robot

If more detail is needed, please tell.

I'm new to ROS so If I say something not right, please let me know.

Thank you in advanced

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/388362/updating-the-urdf-after-changing-the-physical-device-on-the-robot/) by [prem_](https://answers.ros.org/users/86986/prem_/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2021-10-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There is no generic answer to your question, because it depends on your old and new setup. You need to understand what processing was done on the old camera data, and how the new camera is different. Here are some questions to think about (I'm not looking for answers, this is intended to guide your investigation):

- Have you changed the algorithm used to determine depth?
- Is the old/new camera calibrated?
- Has the camera's Optical Transform Frame changed?
- What information is used by the image analysis code?

---

Originally posted by [Mike Scheutzow](https://answers.ros.org/users/75154/mike-scheutzow/) with karma: 4903 on 2021-10-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [prem_](https://answers.ros.org/users/86986/prem_/) on 2022-10-22**:
Thank you very much for your replying, and sorry for late response.

I have come to understand that If I make some changes to the URDF, I have to update the moveit config using the moveit assistant and go through some basic setup like self-collision checking, updating SRDF, etc.

But your questions have made me understand a lot in another point of view.

Thank you again!